# How to enlarge a List(of String)(bytes)

Tags: vb.net, list

I have a variable `Queue` in which I write information from a stream. The variable is initiated as follows:

```
Public Shared Queue As List(Of String) = New List(Of String)(1024)
```

The code to read the stream is

```
Public Shared Sub ReadStreamForever(ByVal stream As Stream)
    Dim encoder = New UTF8Encoding()
    Dim buffer = New Byte(2047) {}
    Dim counter as Integer = 0
    While True
        If stream.CanRead Then
            Dim len As Integer = stream.Read(buffer, 0, 2048)
            Counter = Counter + 1
            If len > 0 Then
                Dim text = encoder.GetString(buffer, 0, len)
                SSEApplication.Push(text)

            Else
                Exit While
            End If
        Else
            Exit While
        End If
    End While
End Sub
```

Where the push methode just does a few string manipulation and adds line after line into the Queue Variable

```
Public Shared Sub Push(ByVal text As String)
    If String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(text) Then
        Return
    End If

    Dim lines = text.Trim().Split(vbLf)
    SSEApplication.Queue.AddRange(lines)
End Sub
```

I have different big datasets I want to stream but the Queue length after filling it up is always 2691, so it looks like it is kind of limited in length. I just do not know where I limit the Queue Variable and how to enlarge it. Could anyone help me here?

Comment: Queue is a `List(Of String)`; it's capacity is limited by the memory your application can address. It doesn't have a `Length`. It has a `Count`, the number of items that it contains, and a `Capacity`, which is increased (possibly doubled) when required. The List automatically expands and increases its Capacity when you add new items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, `List` doesn't have fixed length, `Add` method resizes `List` and makes space for another element.

If you want to have fixed length, you could use simple array: `Dim Queue(1024) As string`

But then, you will get an exception when trying to add more elements, so you can check the condition in `Push` method:

```
If lines.Count < 1024 Then
  SSEApplication.Queue.AddRange(lines)
End If
```

That check will also prevent having more than 1024 elements when using `List`, but if you have collection of fixed length, I would recommend using simple array.

Useful resource: [Arrays in Visual Basic](https://learn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/arrays/), there you can also read, how to enlarge array, when you want to add extra elements using `ReDim` keyword.

Comment: Thank you for your tip. I will try an Array instead, btw. I do not need a capacity. I have edited my question and implemented a counter. Observing that I found out that, no matter what datasource I stream, the counter is always 304 at the end. Do you have any idea why that can be.